# When is next release for s3fs planned

Tags: botocore, python-s3fs

I have tried using 0.4.2 s3fs pip module, moving greater than 5GB files are failing with write fail errors.

There is an issue with 0.4.2 version of s3fs pip module, which got fixed in master. When is next release planned so that i can use this feature.

Can i use master build directly ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing it from source. Refer to the commands below:

```
git clone git@github.com:dask/s3fs
cd s3fs
git checkout master
python setup.py install
```